# How to display chart with changing data while code is running?

Tags: c#

I have a chart in `C#` but I would like to see the points being plotted as my code is executed especially since it takes upwards of 5 minutes or more to finish. It seems to only show the final result. I am using `Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 C# Windows Form Application`.

**Question:** How can I get the chart to show the points being plotted as my code is executed?

**Example:** Instead of showing the final chart with points (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), etc. all filled in already how can I show this chart while my code is executing? So, when it hits the code to plot (0, 0) I actually see it and the moment it hits the code to plot (1, 1) it makes the connection between the two points.

**Edit:** Adding plot code as requested.

```
// Plot the Points on Chart
public void plotPoints(double x, double y)
{
    DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
    dp.XValue = x;
    dp.SetValueY(y);
    chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(dp);
}
```

Comment: You want to read up on multithreading.

Comment: Depends if this is a desktop app or a webapp.

Comment: This is a desktop application.

Comment: It doesn't have to be multithreaded.  The UI thread could force a paint when a new point comes in.

Comment: @recursive Could you post an example code of that method?

Comment: You should post the relevant part of your plotting code

Comment: Are you using the Chart control or are you doing the plotting yourself? The chart control updates itself while you add data points.

Comment: I'm using the Chart control. It does update itself while I add data points but it does not show the points being added one by one, it only shows the final product. Would it be better to create my own graph to accomplish this or can the Chart control do this? @o_weisman I added the relevant part of my plotting code. I call this method each time one iteration of my for loop completes. It plots all the points perfectly fine, but only when the code is finished executing. I would like to see the chart being plotted while the code is executing.

Comment: I believe you are calling plotPoints function from a loop on your UI thread. Since the UI thread is busy in your loop, it can't update the chart until the loop terminates. You will need to either stop the loop and give the UI thread a chance to run and do the updating of the chart, or alternatively, create a background thread that creates the DataPoints and periodically adds a bunch of them to chart1.Series

Comment: @o_weisman Yes, I think that is exactly what I am looking for. How can I do something like that? Is there some tutorial somewhere detailing background threads? I haven't dabbled in threads at least to my knowledge.

Comment: You can use a BackgroundWorker as shown in the topmost answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624474/run-task-asynchronously-in-c-sharp .  The second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888707/asynchronous-execution-in-windows-forms/7888743#7888743 shows how to use a task if you have .NET 4 and above . I'm not sure, but I believe that if you change the Series points in your background thread/worker the GUI will update it without any need for synchronization. I also suggest reading some general material about threads.

Comment: @o_weisman Great, thank you I will take a look at both of these links.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trivial code example that draws lines incrementally.  The UI is unresponsive.  If you don't like that, you will have do your calculations on another thread, which is really too big of a topic for a stack overflow answer.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var t = new Timer();
        t.Tick += DrawGraph;
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Enabled = true;
        t.Start();
    }

    private void DrawGraph(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var rng = new Random();
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        while (true) {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, rng.Next(Width), rng.Next(Height), rng.Next(Width), rng.Next(Height));
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 both for providing incorrect code, and for demonstrating all the bad multithreading practices. Depending on a flavour of Timers (System.Windows.Forms.Timer, System.Threading.Timer) severity of this code example differs. In one case the app is just hung in main thread, using the other - consuming all the cpu and many threads before dying.

Comment: There is no multithreading here at all, much less any multithreading practices.  The timer could be replaced with a button click handler.  It's just a way to start the loop after the form has been loaded.  In any case, this code is horrible, and I would never use it either.  But without any further information about requirements of the original question, it's the best solution I could think of.  (and easiest to write)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using WPF to achieve this as realtime binding is supported "out-of-the-box" with no custom UI code.